# How was China able to maintain a good relation with both Saudi Arabia and Iran?

Tags: china, iran, middle-east, saudi-arabia

> First, India’s energy relationship with Iran hasn’t been without
> strain. New Delhi has had doubts about Tehran’s reliability and
> stability as a supplier. Iran is thought to have reneged on some
> deals, tried to renegotiate others, and given China and its companies
> better terms in the Iranian energy sector. While an Iran under the
> pressure of sanctions has shown slightly more inclination to offer
> India and its companies better terms, Indian officials note that the
> Iranians remain tough negotiators in this arena. Tehran has also not
> been above using India’s oil and gas needs to pressure the Indian
> government in the foreign policy realm. This was perhaps most evident
> when Iranian officials seemed to link energy deals to India’s votes at
> the IAEA. This did nothing to increase New Delhi’s confidence in Iran
> and reinforced its general tendency to diversify its dependence partly
> in order to limit any one country’s leverage on it.
>
> **Second, even as India has ties with Iran, it also has a number of
> other key relationships in the region that will keep it from getting
> too close to Iran.** Saudi Arabia and the other Gulf Cooperation Council
> states supply a significant amount of the oil India imports. Qatar is
> also its largest source of imported natural gas. The large Indian
> diaspora in these countries, which is a major source of remittances,
> and the significant Sunni population in India (over 120 million) also
> make these relationships crucial. In addition, there are existing and
> potential trade and investment ties at stake with these countries. For
> Delhi, a relationship with Riyadh is also particularly critical
> because of the leverage the Saudi government is thought to have with
> Islamabad.

https://www.brookings.edu/articles/indias-relationship-with-iran-its-complicated/

The article seemed to suggest that it's not impossible, but extremely difficult to maintain a close and good relationship with both Iran and Saudi Arabia, which have conflicting interests, and yet China was able to broker a diplomatic normalization between Saudi Arabia and Iran, suggesting that China was able to maintain a good relation with both countries. How did China manage to do that?

Comment: Buys oil from both?

Comment: I have to wonder if this Brookings piece might be in part wishing for the state of affairs it describes. Wrt/ unilateral US sanctions, both China and India, as the likely top two in the long run (simply from their population size), are quite able to prioritize their material interests.